# Prove that the solution to Moser's circle problem is not $2^{n-1}$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

I came across [Moser's circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas) not to long ago as an example of where you shouldn't assume that a pattern continues just because it works for the first few values. (The wrong pattern being that the areas created are $2^{n-1}$ where n is the number of points, starting at 1)

I've seen many examples of proofs that the solution is actually ${n\choose 4} + {n\choose 2} + 1$ however I'm struggling to prove that the answer is not $2^{n-1}$.

I attempted a proof by induction.

Base case: $$2^{1-1} = 2^0 = 1$$
Which is correct for 1 point there is 1 area. The problem is the step case.

Step case:

*Assume that $2^{k-1}$ gives the number of areas*

$$2^{k - 1} + a = 2^{(k+1)-1}$$

... The problem is what is $a$? See I could use the actual proof from above and set $$a = ({(k+1)\choose 4} + {(k+1)\choose 2} + 1) - ({k\choose 4} + {k\choose 2} + 1)$$ but I feel that would be cheating considering it requires knowledge that there is another solution out there. If we didn't know the proof existed and we were looking at this problem for the first time, and we were just trying to prove that our assumption that $2^{n-1}$ was correct (which we know in hindsight that it isn't) I'm not sure how we would go about figuring out what the value of $a$ is. Is there a solution to the problem of what $a$ is? Or is there another proof (excluding proof by exhaustive search) that would show that our logic is wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Not sure about what is your question, especially given that Wikipedia's page you linked includes a proof by induction. Is it "Proof by induction requires to know the expression we want to prove. How do we know this expression?" or "Can we reuse in the step case the expression we want to prove?" or "Can we use a proof by induction to show that a wrong expression is, indeed, wrong?".

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni the wiki page gave a proof by induction that the proof ${n\choose 4} + {n\choose 2} + 1$ works. Nowhere does it disprove $2^{n-1}$ using induction. The question is closer to "how do we disprove $2^{n-1}$ as being a solution to the problem without using knowledge we aquired as a result of knowing $2^{n-1}$ is not the solution.

Comment: "The problem is what is $a$?"  From your assumption, it would follow $a = 2^{k-1}$.  But you might be overthinking this.  To show that $2^{n-1}$ is incorrect you can simply evaluate that expression for a modest value of $n$ that gives a different value than the correct expression $\binom{n}{4} + \binom{n}{2} + 1$.  Although these expressions agree in value for very small $n$,  one of them grows exponentially with $n$ while the other is a fourth degree polynomial in $n$.  The latter will quickly "fall behind" the exponential growth of the former.

Comment: "From your assumption, it would follow $a = 2^{k-1}$". If we had a circle with k points, we would have $2^{k-1}$ areas (based on the assumption). If we added another point we must arrive at $2^{(k+1)-1}$ (based on the assumption). If we then assumed $a$ it would be the equivalent of just assuming we are right (because at this point we assumed everything), so how did you get to $a = 2^{k-1}$ ?@hardmath

Comment: "you can simply evaluate that expression for a modest value of n that gives a different value than the correct expression ${n\choose 4} + {n\choose 2} + 1$" - the issue here is you have an answer and you are checking the results against said answer. The first person to try to prove their theory didn't have this, they just had their theory